# Create a hyperlink to external website in django

Tags: django, django-templates, href

I have a little problem about creating a hyperlink to an external website in django, for example in to the google.com
I have in my html file something like :

```
Adres www: <a href="{{ det_wpisu.adres_www }}">{{ det_wpisu.adres_www }}</a> <br />
```

but the www address when I click showing me :

```
http://localhost:8000/detale/3/www.google.com
```

and returned the 404 page.

Comment: What is the value in your html? It could be normal if you didn't put `http://` before your link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure the variable `det_wpisu.adres_www` contains a **full URL** including `https://`, eg:

```
context = {'det_wpisu.adres_www': 'https://www.google.com'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider embed solution with use `http` . So it will be like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to add the http:// string in your Django template. Instead of modifying the views and/or the database, try this...

```
<a href="http://{{ det_wpisu.adres_www }}">{{ det_wpisu.adres_www }}</a>
```